# How to define a beans in application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms, javabeans

I have configuration with two beans:

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(jmsConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsComponent jms(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        return JmsComponent.jmsComponentClientAcknowledge(jmsConnectionFactory);
    }
}
```

bean description is not spring-boot approach.
I tried define in application.yml and deleted code but it's doesn't work

```
camel:
    jms:
        session:
            acknowledge:
                 mode: CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The relative path of application.yml file is `/myApplication/src/main/resources/application.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for camel-jms spring boot auto-configuration and the names of the options: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration - there you can see its named `camel.component.jms.acknowledgement-mode-name`

Also make sure you are using `camel-jms-starter` as dependency in the pom.xml to use spring boot starters.